# Android-Windows 8: What software do you recommend to screencast playing a game?

Tags: windows, android, screen-recording

What software do you recommend to make a screencast of a game?
Similar to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh-CJstr_QA) would be ideal.

For Windows 8, I have seen that Camtasia is good for other software in the desktop.. but Is it different with games?

I'm interested in a solution for both Android and Windows 8.

Comment: A few questions: What price range is acceptable? Do you need the same solution for both Android & Windows?

Comment: I don´t mind if are diferent software in android from in win8.

The prices... depends on how good is the software, but I´m a particular and it´s for my use.

Answer (score 1):

Camtasia is [not recording](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/camtasia_is_not_recording_full_screen_games-1a65e7) fullscreen games.

To make a screencast of a fullscreen game on Windows you can use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/).

A free solution , but only if you have a Nvidia graphics card is [Nvidia Geforce Experience 2.0](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience).

On Android use [androidscreencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbdT2bDAwlg) is a tutorial.